# ¿Cómo hacer para que una propiedad de un objeto sea de solo lectura?

Tags: javascript

Estoy queriendo hacer un ejercicio con objetos en *JavaScript*. Debo crear un objeto llamado película donde deberá tener: `id`, `titulo`, `descripción`, `año`, `duración`, `actores` y `director`.

Deberá tener métodos para editar todas sus propiedades, menos el *ID*, además un método para agregar y/o eliminar actores, así como para consultar el objeto.

Yo realice lo siguiente:

```
function pelicula (id, title, year, descripcion, actores, director) {

    var o = this;

    o.id = id;
    o.title = title;
    o.year = year;
    o.descripcion = descripcion;
    o.actores = actores;
    o.director = director;

    o.getInfo = function (){
            return 'o.title + o.descripcion + o.descripcion + o.year + o.actores + o.director';
    }
}
var movie = new pelicula('id','Escuadron Suicida', 2016 , 'es una película de supervillanos4 estadounidense de 2016, basada en el equipo de antihéroes homónimo de DC Comics' , 'Will Smith - Jared Leto - Margot Robbie - Joel Kinnaman - Viola Davis - Jai Courtney - Jay Hernández - Adewale Akinnuoye-Agbaje', 'David Ayer');

console.log(movie,movie.title,movie.getInfo());
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la propiedad `id` no pueda ser modificada, es decir, que sea de solo lectura?

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Perdón, no escribí la pregunta: Quería saber si el ejercicio lo estaba encarando bien.

Comment: Va bien la parte de que inicializas algunas de tus variables, `getInfo` solo te regresará un string con ese texto, debes quitar las comillas para que te mande las variables, y para los actores te sugiero uses un arreglo para que puedas irlos guardando de uno a uno, pero la pregunta es muy amplia, debe de ser algo mucho más específico que ver si vas bien en el ejercicio. Probalemente te la cierren.

Comment: Te faltan los métodos para agregar los actores (y porque no? eliminarlos también), estos deberás manejarlo en una matriz, para la función `getInfo` te sugiero manejarlo como un **Objecto** mas que como una **Candena**.

Comment: como seria eso?

Answer (score 1):

Para crear una propiedad del objeto que sea **"solo lectura"** deberás usar el metodo [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/defineProperty) el cual permite crear una propiedad del objeto y definir sus atributos tales como: `writable:[true/false], value:[number, object, function, etc]`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como crear la clase incluyendo el método para **Crear** y **Eliminar** autores:

```js
function pelicula(id, title, year, descripcion, actores, director) {

 // hacer que la propiedad ID sea de solo lectura:
 Object.defineProperty(this, "id", {
  writable: false,
  value: id
 });

 // las demás propiedades se pueden crear directamente
 // Sin usar el método: Object.defineProperty()
 this.title = title;
 this.year = year;
 this.descripcion = descripcion;
 this.actores = [];
 this.director = director;

 // Función para crear nuevos actores:
 this.actorAdd = function (e) {
  if (typeof e !== "string") {
   for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
     this.actores.push(e[i]);
   };
  } else {
    this.actores.push(e);
  }
  return actores.length;
 }
 this.actorAdd(actores);

 // Función para Eliminar actores ya creados:
 this.actorRemove = function (e) {
  if (typeof e !== "string") {
   for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    this.actores = this.actores.filter(function(s) {return e[i]!=s});
   };
  } else {
    this.actores = this.actores.filter(function(s) {return e!=s});
  }
  return this.actores.length;
 }
 // Función para mostrar Información del objeto:
 this.getInfo = function () {
  var info = {};
  for (var i in this) {
   if (typeof this[i] != "function")
    info[i] = this[i];
  }
  return info;
 }
}
console.log('// Crea la Clase Película (con un solo actor: "Will Smith")');
var movie = new pelicula('001','Escuadron Suicida', 2016 , 'es una película de supervillanos4 estadounidense de 2016, basada en el equipo de antihéroes homónimo de DC Comics' , "Will Smith", 'David Ayer');
console.log(movie.getInfo());

console.log('// Añade los demás Actores:');
movie.actorAdd(["Jared Leto","Margot Robbie","Joel Kinnaman","Viola Davis","Jai Courtney","Jay Hernández","Adewale Akinnuoye-Agbaje"]);
console.log(movie.getInfo());

console.log('// Elimina algunos Actores:');
movie.actorRemove(["Will Smith","Jared Leto","Margot Robbie","Joel Kinnaman","Viola Davis"]);
console.log(movie.getInfo());

console.log('// intenta modificar el id (solo lectura):');
console.log(movie.id);
movie.id = "002";
console.log(movie.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
//Definición de... ¿clase?
function pelicula (
    id, 
    title, 
    year, 
    descripcion, 
    actores, 
    director
) {

    var _id             = id,
        _title          = title,
        _year           = year,
        _descripcion    = descripcion,
        _actores        = actores,
        _director       = director;


    this.getInfo = function () {

        return "" 
           + _title 
           + _descripcion 
           + _descripcion 
           + _year 
           + _actores 
           + _director;
    }
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////
//Creamos el objeto
var movie = new pelicula(
    'id',
    'Escuadron Suicida', 
    2016, 
    'Película de estadounidense de 2016, basada en el equipo de antihéroes homónimo de DC Comics', 
    'Will Smith - Jared Leto - Margot Robbie - Joel Kinnaman - Viola Davis - Jai Courtney - Jay Hernández - Adewale Akinnuoye-Agbaje', 
    'David Ayer'
);


///////////////////////////////////////////////
//Test
console.log( movie );
console.log( movie._title );
console.log( movie.getInfo( ));
```

Lo modifique ligeramente. Uso poco JS yo la verdad. Si te aconsejo, separar en diferentes llamadas lo que quieres ver por consola en cada momento.
Saludos.

Comment: Genial, gracias el dato Orici lo voy a tener en cuenta

Comment: De nada. También si te fijas en la disposición multi-línea, de las variables, datos, etc. además de ayudar a ver mejor el código, es un estilo que se esta imponiendo porque ayuda con el control de versiones con Git.